# Android - getView() и getDropDownView() не вызываются.

Tags: android, android-spinner, java, adapter

Доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь написать простенький адаптер для Spinner, суть проста: используются стандартные ресурсы системы (`android.R.layout.simple_spinner_...`), но кроме текста я хочу приписать туда тег. В итоге адаптер не работает, а методы `getView(...)` и `getDropDownView(...)` не вызываются. Как это исправить? Код:

---

```
//PresetsAdapter
public class PresetsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
ArrayList<Preset> mData;
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mInflater;
Utilities utils;

public PresetsAdapter(Context ctx, int resourceId, ArrayList<Preset> values)
{
    super(ctx, resourceId);
    mContext = ctx;
    mData = values;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    utils = new Utilities(mContext);
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    utils.Log("Spinner Adapter - getView");
    View v = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parent, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    tv.setText(mData.get(pos).name);
    tv.setTag(mData.get(pos).data);

    return v;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    utils.Log("Spinner Adapter - getDropDownView");
    View v = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);

    CheckedTextView tv = (CheckedTextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    tv.setText(mData.get(pos).name);
    tv.setTag(mData.get(pos).data);

    return v;
}
}
```

---

```
//Preset
public class Preset {
String name = "";
String data = "";

public Preset(String n, String d)
{
    this.name = n;
    this.data = d;
}
}
```

---

```
//Ставлю адаптер

    Spinner presets = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.eq_presets);
    ArrayList<Preset> mPresets = new ArrayList<Preset>();
    mPresets.add(new Preset("test1", "test1"));
    mPresets.add(new Preset("test2", "test2"));
    PresetsAdapter pa = new PresetsAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mPresets);
    presets.setAdapter(pa);
```

---

---

Comment: Ну же, помогите!

Comment: a getCount() переопределили? От куда адаптер узнает, сколько в нем элементов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена, надо было в конструкторе класса приписать ко всем объектам `this`.

```
public PresetsAdapter(Context ctx, int resourceId, ArrayList<Preset> values)
{
    super(ctx, resourceId, values);
    this.mContext = ctx;
    this.mData = values;
    this.mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.utils = new Utilities(mContext);
}
```

Comment: какое-то очень сомнительное решение...

Comment: Честно говоря, я и сам удивился, но всё же это работает.

Comment: Утверждать не буду, но у super класса названия полей могут совпадать. Я при дебаге один раз очень удивился, когда увидел у объекта класса-наследника CursorAdapter 2 поля с именами mContext. Возможно, без this у Вас инициализировались именно поля super класса.